# Is there a quicker way to open a single file in different programs?

Tags: windows-10, tiff, dropdownlist

This question is asked because I use .Tif files, and need to alternately open them in a photo viewer to quickly see files and an image editor to work on them.

It's not an urgent problem, but I notice that in Windows 10, the second open in the drop down menu for .tif files is edit in Paint 3D, and I'm wondering if its possible to pin items from the >'open with' sub menu to the top, to streamline the process?